# Include Custom Control dynamically on XPage

Tags: custom-controls, xpages

I am trying to include custom control on XPage based on some conditions. These conditions are depends on certain user selection fields. So As user changes his selection, I am populating the custom control name, and trying to include it in XPage. 
I read about , but it loads the give page during Page load, and I am not able to load it dynamically.

example code Snippet :

```
<xp:button id="button3" value="Change Page to Include CC 2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" disableValidators="true" refreshId="pnlRefresh">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.ccPageName = "content_CC2"}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:panel id="pnlRefresh">
    <xp:include>
        <xp:this.pageName><![CDATA[${javascript:sessionScope.ccPageName + ".xsp";}]]> </xp:this.pageName>
    </xp:include>
</xp:panel>
```

Is there any possibility to achieve this requirement? Or using JAVA how do we inject page dynamically in XPage code?

I don't want to use Dynamic Content Control or Switch Control from ExtLib, as I will need to include all the required custom controls (Hardcoded) then only I can display the specific CC based on criteria.

Please help me.

Comment: If you notice your code for `xp:include` component you will see **`$`** in front of the formula for `pageName`. This indicates that this formula would be evaluated on page load. There is no option in XPage for this formula to be evaluated dynamically as you require. You could look at [this blog by Keith Strickland where he explains Component Injection on the fly](http://xprentice.gbs.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/d6plinks/KSTD-8MGJTA). May be this could give you some ideas.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the Dynamic Content Control? and why do you need to include all the required custom controls? If you are including the required custom controls anyway, you could use partial refresh to have them render or not.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use Dynamic Content control. I want to load the custom control based on user selection. So the requirement is like : When page loads initially there are no custom control loaded on the page, User clicks on some parameters, then the corresponding custom control should load.

Comment: As I said that `pageName` is evaluated on page load of `xp:include`, you write the code to return custom control's name and then reload the  entire page and **not** partial refresh the custom control.

Comment: think twice about your wish... are you aware of page lifecycle and thus side effects of your feature? if user switches his selection, previous control will vanish and user loses data. I think ExtLib Dynamic content is better solution.

Comment: Yes, thats true. The Issue I am facing here is there are hundreds of custom controls, but use only one based on user selection. If I use ExtLib Dynamic content, I have to hard code these hundred custom control name and Key. Is there any better solution I can use for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve what You want:

1. Use Dynamic Content Control - its not true that You have to include all controls in order to make it work - there is a hack that allows You to simply rebuild the content of this control (calling show method with null parameter), here is an example: http://pastebin.com/VEDAjdDJ
2. Build Your control from java using custom control builder. An example of this can be found in Extension Library source code (class com.ibm.xsp.extlib.builder.ControlBuilder). This is a bit harder than first way so I would advise You to use Dynamic Content Control!

Remember that after rebuilding content of control all data kept in controls that is not saved will be lost! The best way to handle this problem is to use managed beans to keep Your data away from UI controls.